# Can I configure Chromium or Firefox to allow extensions everywhere?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, chromium

I want to be able to use extensions like vimium and a color inverter on every page, including the builtins like `chrome://settings` or `about:newtab`.

Neither Firefox or Chromium allow extensions to modify builtin pages.

Can this behavior be changed? I'm not partial to either browser in particular, I just need it to work in one of them. I'm happy to mess around with the sources and recompile if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

WebExtensions cannot modify `about:` or `chrome://` pages, so the behavior you mention cannot be changed. This is the only extensions API supported by both Firefox and Chrome since the former has dropped support for XUL extensions.

Extensions can inject content scripts into tabs that match URL patterns or specific tabs via `tabs.executeScript()`. Both methods take a "match pattern" for the target page that starts with `<scheme>` which must be `http[s]`, `file`, `ftp`, or `app` (for Firefox), so any access to `chrome://` or `about:` URLs is impossible. The CSS injection API `tabs.insertCSS()` uses the match pattern as well and cannot be used to modify protected pages.

Extensions can also have background scripts that don't have access to web pages and must modify them indirectly through content scripts, so they fall under the same restrictions.

Since the source code of both Firefox and Chromium is available, you can certainly make the changes necessary to grant extensions extra permissions, but there isn't something as simple as a compile-time switch.

Keyboard shortcuts registered through a background script are effective on all pages, but the API necessary for truly arbitrary key combinations does not exist at this time. If you are styling Firefox, you might be able to affect `about:` pages with `userChrome.css` modifications.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/executeScript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/insertCSS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts